# Docker compose npm script command not found

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, next.js

I want to make the website with React (NextJS) and connect to MongoDB database. I decided to use docker compose and I got some problem. I can't run `yarn run dev` command when I run `docker-compose up`.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/opt/web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  mongodb:
    image: "tutum/mongodb"
    environment:
      - MONGODB_PASS=something
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
      - "28017:28017"
```

Here is my Dockerfile (inside frontend folder)

```
FROM node:alpine

MAINTAINER Chun Rapeepat <chunza2542@hotmail.com>

ENV NODE_ENV development
ENV APP /opt/web

RUN mkdir -p $APP
WORKDIR $APP
RUN npm install -g yarn

COPY package.json $APP/
COPY /pages $APP/pages

RUN cd $APP && yarn

CMD ["yarn", "run", "dev"]
```

When I run `docker-compose up` command I got message like this

```
sh: next: not found
```

What should I fix this, thx.

Comment: Post complete logs

Comment: can you show us your package.json file?